# Saving New Product Attribute Doesn't Save

Tags: php, magento-1

I was wondering whether you could assist me with an issue that I have had for some period of time. I am trying to add product description and specification tabs to each product.

I am following this simple guide to achieve [this](https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/add-custom-tabs/):

The error I'm getting is on step 1: Creating an attribute;

When creating the attribute and saving, the attribute created doesn't save and in fact just 'grey's out' the 'Save Attribute' & 'Save and Continue edit' buttons:

[image: grey buttons]

Which stops me progressing. Can anyone think of a reason as to why this would be happening?

Any answers appreciated greatly.